# Reinstalling OS on a VM

Tags: linux, suse, rhel8

I don't know what is going on and I need help here please:

I have SUSE 15 on my VM and I want to change it to RHEL 8, after following thru with normal configuration (changing the ISO to Redhat8 - Changing the VM Option settings > General Options > Guest OS to Linux > Guest OS Version to RHEL 8 and save it.

I was still unable to update the VM to boot from RHEL 8. Is there anything that I am missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SUSE 15 on my VM and I want to change it to RHEL 8

That is a complete reinstall. You can't just change it, even though it's `rpm` based.

The easiest thing to do would be to delete the VM and recreate it.